# how to check if a file is a .gz file in Python

Tags: python, io

I am working on python input-output and was given a CSV file(possible gzipped)
. If it is gzipped, I have to decompress it, and then read it.

I was trying to read the first two bytes do like this:

```
def func(filename):
    fi = open(filenam,"rb")
    byte1 = fi.read(1)
    byte2 = fi.read(1)
```

then I will check `byte1` and `byte2` to see if they are equal to `0x1f` and `0x8b`, then decompress it then print every line of it.

But when I run it, I got this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I'm new to python, can anyone help?

Comment: It doesn't look like this snippet is what causes it. Please add more code.

Comment: Please create a **complete** short program that demonstrates the error. Start with the program you have, and remove everything unrelated to the error message. Then copy-paste (do not retype) that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://SSCCE.org

Comment: that's all I have in the function :(

Comment: Then it is not happening in this function. Please copy-paste the code.

Comment: like others have said, please add some more code:) and when you `open(filenam)` do you mean `open(filename)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use endwith() in Python to check whether a folder has .gz extension file then use gzip module to decompress it and read .gz contents

```
import os
import gzip
for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Directory_name"):
    if file.endswith(".gz"):
        print file
        os.chdir(r"C:\Directory_name")
        f = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
        file_content = f.read()
        f.close()
```

so here "file_content" variable will hold the data of your csv gzipped file

Comment: how do we read it line by line? Like we decompress while reading?

Comment: then you need to use readlines() instead of read() for a file object ;so it will store all csv content line by line in a list variable

Comment: This only checks if the file has an extension.  Not whether the content is gzipped or not.  What do you do if the files aren't names .gz? What do you do if they don't have an extension at all?

Answer (score 2):

Understanding from what you said in the comment - "that's all I have in the function" I would assume the issue is that the function has no return value. So probably the caller of the function tries to run on the result of a function call with no return value, i.e  NoneType.